# Skip-gram gradient with respect to outer word vector

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, natural-language, word2vec

For the skip gram model we know the naive softmax loss is as follows;-

$$ J=-\log(p(o \mid c)) = -\log\left(\frac {\exp\left(u_{o}^{T} v_{c}\right)}{\sum_{w=1}^{W}\exp\left(u_{w}^{T} v_{c}\right)}\right)$$

I wanted to know the derivative $\frac{\partial J}{\partial u_w}$ which is the derivative of $J$ with respect to the outer word vectors, and how does it make a difference if $w=o$ and $w \neq o$.

If I try to go via the matrix calculus way. I get that $\frac{\partial J}{\partial U}=v_c(\hat{y}-y)^T$ where $\hat{y}, y, v_c$ are all column vectors. So basically $\frac{\partial J}{\partial u_w}$ is just the $w$ row of $\frac{\partial J}{\partial U}$ and it doesn't make a difference if $w=o$ or not. However,  when I try to differentiate the above expression normally, I am getting different answers.

When $w=o$ I just differentiate $-\log\left(\exp\left(u_{o}^{T} v_{c}\right)\right)$  and $-\log\left( \sum_{w=1}^{W} \exp\left(u_{w}^{T} v_{c}\right)\right)$   and when $w \neq 0$ I just differentiate $-\log\left( \sum_{w=1}^{W} \exp\left(u_{w}^{T} v_{c}\right)\right)$ treating the other term as constant.

Can someone let me know if both the matrix calculus way and the normal way provide the same answers or am I doing something wrong? Also, please provide the answers if possible.

P.S. - I am following the stanford cs 224n course